# XCUIElement always exist

Tags: xcode7, ios9, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I try UI Testing on xcode 7 beta.

After an XCUIElement dismissed, its `.exists` property still remains YES.

e.g.

```
XCUIElement *button = app.sheets[@"Sample sheet"].buttons[@"Sample button"];
[button tap]; // Tapping will dismiss UIActionSheet and its button will no longer exist.
XCTAssertFalse(button.exists); // -> Error here.
```

Is there any way to detect an XCUIElement not exists after being dismissed?

Comment: For anyone else looking the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33248181/228981

Answer (score 2):

XCUIElement has an exists method which returns BOOL.

In your code:

```
if (button.exists) {
   [button tap];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to check an XCUIElement exists and hitable or not before fire a tap event

In your code:

```
if (button.exists && button.isHitable) {
   [button tap];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for app.sheets.count