# XCUITest : Is it possible to tap on element not using static texts present but identifier?

Tags: swift, xcode8, xcuitest

I am currently trying to automate tests with XCUITest framework for a parking mobile app. The thing is, each time I click on a button, I don't want to click on the static text associated to the element (because the text changes) but on the ID. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: please provide your trial code.

Comment: What do you mean by clicking on the ID instead of the static text ? You can look for static texts with the ID instead of the label

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS XCUITests access element by accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442932/ios-xcuitests-access-element-by-accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

You can match an element by its identifier using `matching(identifier:)` function

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500679-matching

Chain `.firstmatch` or `.element` to match the single element.

Comment: This approach might have problems if you have elements without unique Accessibility IDs but containing unique data.