# Wait for page to load completely and content become visible. XCUI Appliction

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcuitest, xcuiautomation

```
for i in 1......1000{
    sleep(5)
    makeScreenshot(name:  "Page-\(i)")
    app.swipeLeft()
}
```

Instead of sleep I want to implement dynamic wait that waits for page to load completely and content on each page becomes visible before taking screenshot.

I tried using `XCUIApplication().waitForExcistence(timeout: 10)` but it didn't work as expected it took screenshot before content become visible for some pages.

I also tried this Function from ChatGpt, but it didn't work as expected it took screenshot before content become visible for some pages.

```
func waitForAppQuiescence(timeout: TimeInterval) { 
    let quiescenceExpectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "exists ==                              true"), object: XCUIApplication()) 
    let result XCTWaiter().wait(for: [quiescenceExpectation], timeout: timeout) 
    if result =  .completed { 
        print("Timed out waiting for the app to become quiescent")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing if an element is visible with Xcode 7 UITest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247116/testing-if-an-element-is-visible-with-xcode-7-uitest)

Comment: lazarevzubov - the solution you provided checks for a particular element(static text) on the page but I don't have any particular element as every page has different text content. And i want to take screenshot of everypage after page is loaded and text content is visible.

Comment: Your wait must predicate on something. An interval of time or an object XCUITest can see. If you can provide more information on your application structure perhaps we could provide some ideas?

Comment: It's an e-learning platform which has epubs (ebooks) and I have to take screenshots of these ebook of every page and next page comes by swiping left.